# Javascript - for loop not filtering array correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am making a hangman program where you choose a word and the program guesses which word it is one letter at a time.

It can correctly remove words containing the worng letters and guess optimally, but it can't see when correctly guessed letters are in the incorrect places, and deletes every word in the array.

Here is my code:

```
function wrongplace() {
    let newlistword = blankword.split(""); //blankword is the parts of the word the computer can see e.g. "_ _ _ _ a _ _"
    for (let i = 0; i < possible.length; i++) { //possible is the array containing all words that the computer thinks your word might be
        let templistword = possible[i].split("");
        for (let j = 0; j < templistword.length; j++) {
            if ((templistword[j] == newlistword[j]) || (newlistword[j] == "_" && (correct.includes(templistword[ 
                    j] == false)))) { //correct is the letters the computer has guessed correctly
                continue;
            }
            possible.splice(i, 1);
            i--;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

What this is supposed to do is check every possible word, check every letter to either be the same as the guessed word, or the letter in the guessed word to be blank and the letter in the same position in the word it's checking to not be in the correctly guessed letters.

For example:

With this input:

```
var blankword = "____a__"

var possible = ['abandon', 'bombard', 'garland', 'volcano', 'volubly']

var correct = ["a"]
```

When I run `console.log(possible);`, the array is empty when it should return `['bombard', 'volcano']`. Does anyone have any ideas on how to make it not delete everything?

Comment: Since `a` is already in `correct`, shouldn't that cause `bombard` and `volcano` to be excluded too?

Comment: No, I don't think so, because it checks that if the letter with the same position in `blankword` is `"_"` that that letter also shouldn't be in `correct`. None of the other letters that are blanks in `blankword` are `a` in `bombard` or `volcano`.

Comment: what is your expected output when running `wrongplace()` with this input?

Comment: My expected output, as I said in the end, is `['bombard', 'volcano']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.filter` is a better way to solve the problem, here just to point out a little mistake in your code that made it not working:

```
correct.includes(templistword[j] == false) // <----- here, you put `== false` in the parentheses, 
                                           //          which should be after it
```

correct this then your code will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
var blankword = "____a__"

var possible = ['abandon', 'bombard', 'garland', 'volcano', 'volubly']

var correct = ["a"]


function wrongplace() {
    const res = []
    let newlistword = blankword.split(""); //blankword is the parts of the word the computer can see e.g. "_ _ _ _ a _ _"
    //  newlistword = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "a", "_", "_"]
    for (let i = 0; i < possible.length; i++) { //possible is the array containing all words that the computer thinks your word might be
        let templistword = possible[i].split("");
        // templistword = ["a", "b", "a", "n", "d", "o", "n"]
        let j
        for (j = 0; j < templistword.length; j++) {
            if ((templistword[j] == newlistword[j]) || (newlistword[j] == "_" && (!correct.includes(templistword[j])))) { //correct is the letters the computer has guessed correctly
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }
        if (j === templistword.length){
            res.push(possible[i])
        }
    }
    return res;
}

wrongplace()  // ["bombard", "volcano"]
```